# Training of Hopfield network in Matlab

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

I have a matrix 35x5 with -1/1 representing letters (one column one letter). I present the network the matrix as attractors. After, I flip 3 pixels to see if the net is able to recall the correct patterns.

```
%Present the attractors
net = newhop(T);
[Y,Pf,Af] = sim(net,length(T),[],T);

%After I distort 3 pixels, I check if in 50 steps the net can retrieve the shapes
T_dist = {T_dist};
steps = 50;
[Y_dist,Pf,Af] = net({steps},{},T_dist);
Y_dist = Y_dist{1,steps};
Y_dist = Y_dist';
```

But whatever I try, it seems that the training does not work, because I always retrieve the same matrix as the one I distorted.

So I have a) error somewhere or b) the net is not able to recall the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally made it work. This is the correct code for training:

```
T_dist = {T_dist};
steps = 500;
[Y_dist,Pf,Af] = sim(net,{num_letters steps}, {}, T_dist);
Y_dist = Y_dist{1,steps};
```

And I messed up with shape of target arrays. Pay attention for shape of the input when creating the net and training it.